# Is there a recommended best practice for structuring dictionaries to avoid shadowing keys at the same level of nesting?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to understand how much "work" takes place in the background when writing a few lines of code in Tcl for dictionaries, specifcially `dict with...{}`. I'm sure this is a very novice if not stupid question and I may be getting confused trying to represent an object in a dictionary and trying to get the equivalent of a reference to a nested property in the object.

Suppose there are ten keys at some nested level in the dictionary, one of which is itself a dictionary, and I want to iterate over the keys of it.

If use `dict with varName ... key_10` then can't iterate over the keys of the dictionary in `key_10` because they are now shadowed variables in the body; and, if try to do so, an error is thrown stating something about a missing key or that key_10 doesn't exist. If use `dict with` at the level above `key_10` then can iterate over the keys of the dictionary held in `key_10` but shadow variables are generated for the other nine (or 10) keys at that level for which no code in the body relates.

My question is, when used in this manner, should dictionary nested paths be structured in a way that eliminates this shadowing of undesired variables, such as having each termination point end in a sort of useless name that can result in a single variable being shadowed? Is there a recommended best practice of some sort?

So, in this `key_10` example, the dictionary held in `key_10` would be moved to `key_10 data`, such that can use `dict with varName ... key_10 { ... }` and the only shadow variable is `data`; and can then iteratate of the keys of the dictionary now held in `data` rather than `key_10`?

Please excuse my very uncreative example but it illustrates the question.

Thank you.

```
set example [dict create a {b { c {d {key_0 {This is key_0}}}}}]
foreach key {key_1 key_2 key_3 key_4 key_5 key_6 key_7 key_8 key_9 key_10} {
  dict set example a b c d $key "This is $key"
}
dict set example a b c d key_10 {firstName Joe lastName Doakes age 50 height 72 weight 195}
dict with example a b c d key_10 {
  dict for {key value} $key_10 {
    puts "$key : $value"
  }
}
# can't read "key_10": no such variable
dict with example a b c d {
  dict for {key value} $key_10 {
    puts "$key : $value"
  }
  puts $key_0
  puts $key_1
  puts $key_2
  puts $key_3
  puts $key_4
  puts $key_5
  puts $key_6
  puts $key_7
  puts $key_8
  puts $key_9
}
# firstName : Joe
# lastName : Doakes
# age : 50
# height : 72
# weight : 195
# This is key_0
# This is key_1
# This is key_2
# This is key_3
# This is key_4
# This is key_5
# This is key_6
# This is key_7
# This is key_8
# This is key_9

unset key_0
unset key_1
unset key_2
unset key_3
unset key_4
unset key_5
unset key_6
unset key_7
unset key_8
unset key_9

set example [dict create a {b { c {d {key_0 {Zero-index item}}}}}]
foreach key {key_1 key_2 key_3 key_4 key_5 key_6 key_7 key_8 key_9 key_10} {
  dict set example a b c d $key "This is $key"
}
dict set example a b c d key_10 {data {firstName Joe lastName Doakes age 50 height 72 weight 195}}
dict with example a b c d key_10 {
  dict for {key value} $data {
    puts "$key : $value"
  }
  puts $key_0
  puts $key_1
  puts $key_2
  puts $key_3
  puts $key_4
  puts $key_5
  puts $key_6
  puts $key_7
  puts $key_8
  puts $key_9
  puts $key_10
}
# firstName : Joe
# lastName : Doakes
# age : 50
# height : 72
# weight : 195
# can't read "key_0": no such variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be a question of which style you prefer, but I would avoid `dict with` in these sorts of situations.  Some of the language of your question suggests that you're mentally modelling it as doing something different to what it actually is ("shadowing"):

```
set d {foo dictfoo bar dictbar}
set foo outerfoo
dict with d {
    puts $foo    ;# prints "dictfoo"
}
puts $foo        ;# prints "dictfoo", not "outerfoo"
puts $bar        ;# prints "dictbar" - the variables persist
```

that is: the variable `foo` in the `dict with` scope doesn't "shadow" the earlier `foo` variable, it replaces its contents, an effect that persists after the `dict with` scope.  So `dict with` should be used with great caution because it alters the program state (the set of variables that exist and their contents) in a way that is not constrained by the code, but the data (the contents of the dictionary).

This can easily have security implications if that data is sourced from a user (for example form parameters in a web backend).  Imagine in this example that `form_dict` is a command that returns a dictionary containing the form data from the HTTP request we're serving (which we expect to contain "name" and "address"):

```
set is_admin [check_user_is_admin]
set form [form_dict]
dict with form {
    puts "name is: $name"
    puts "address is: $address"
}
if {$is_admin} {
    do_something_privileged
}
```

Then an attacker can craft a request like `/form_handler?name=My%20name&address=xxx&is_admin=1` and `do_something_privileged` will run regardless of what `check_user_is_admin` returned.

A similar problem would happen if the dict you're unpacking with `dict with` is a row in a database result from `select * from foo`, and later a new column is added to table `foo`: that would result in a variable of the name of the new column being set in the code calling `dict with`, altering the *meaning* of the code in the `dict with`, **and after it**, without the code being changed.

Since in your example you're only reading the contents of the dictionary, I'd write it like:

```
set example [dict create a {b { c {d {key_0 {This is key_0}}}}}]
foreach key {key_1 key_2 key_3 key_4 key_5 key_6 key_7 key_8 key_9 key_10} {
    dict set example a b c d $key "This is $key"
}
dict set example a b c d key_10 {firstName Joe lastName Doakes age 50 height 72 weight 195}

dict for {key value} [dict get $example a b c d key_10] {
    puts "$key : $value"
}

set nested  [dict get $example a b c d]
dict for {key value} [dict get $nested key_10] {
    puts "$key : $value"
}
puts [dict get $nested key_0]
puts [dict get $nested key_1]
puts [dict get $nested key_2]
puts [dict get $nested key_3]
puts [dict get $nested key_4]
puts [dict get $nested key_5]
puts [dict get $nested key_6]
puts [dict get $nested key_7]
puts [dict get $nested key_8]
puts [dict get $nested key_9]
```

In terms of the work done "behind the scenes" to access the data, I'd advise you to measure the performance for your use case, using `timerate` if your Tcl version is new enough, or `time` in a byte-coded context (`proc` body for instance).  Since `dict` is in the core and is byte code compiled the performance can be better than your intuition about what it's doing:

```
set dict {
    a   "value of a"
    b   "value of b"
    c   "value of c"
    d   "value of d"
    e   "value of e"
    f   "value of f"
    g   "value of g"
    h   "value of h"
    i   "value of i"
    j   "value of j"
    k   "value of k"
    l   "value of l"
    m   "value of m"
    n   "value of n"
    o   "value of o"
    p   "value of p"
    q   "value of q"
    r   "value of r"
    s   "value of s"
    t   "value of t"
    u   "value of u"
    v   "value of v"
    w   "value of w"
    x   "value of x"
    y   "value of y"
    z   "value of z"
}
puts "using dict get:  [timerate {
    set foo "[dict get $dict a] [dict get $dict m] [dict get $dict z]"
}]"
puts "using dict with: [timerate {
    dict with dict {
        set foo "$a $m $z"
    }
}]"
```

On my system with an optimised build of Tcl 8.7, I get:

```
using dict get:  0.190637 µs/# 5245581 # 5245581 #/sec 1000.000 net-ms
using dict with: 1.657568 µs/# 603294 # 603293 #/sec 1000.001 net-ms
```

This result might be surprising, but consider that `dict with` has to do a lot of work:

- Iterate all the keys in the dict and create or update local variables for them.
- Trace those variables for the duration of the code in the scope of the `dict with` or otherwise arrange to propagate changes to those variables back into the dict.

Whereas `dict get` just has to read those keys.

Comment: Thank you. I coded my project like you suggested before posting and then wondered about the work of copying the data over using `dict get`. Likely I get too focused on trying to use the same memory locations when I don't need an independent copy. I've been prefixing all dictionary keys that point to simple values with 'D_' just to keep track of which are from a `dict with`.  Thanks for the warnings and advice.

Comment: Tcl is unusual in that regard - it isn't "copying the data over".  What feels like "pass by value" (ie. copying) isn't - behind the scenes what is happening is passing a pointer to the value and incrementing a reference count: Tcl values are COW - copy on write.  So just passing around a value for read is as cheap as you can get - you just get a shared reference.  When a shared value is changed, behind the scenes the value is duplicated (which is often very efficient and not a full copy), and the new, private, unshared value is altered and stored back into the variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. I never heard of COW before. . I was reading over these two answers again and noticed how this one suggests that the langauge I used indicates a flawed mental model of how `dict with` works; and I concur with that conclusion, of course. But it got me to wondering from whence did I get that term "shadowing" because it's not one I use and I'm just not that clever with words to come up with it. I found it in Ashock Nadkarni's text on Tcl p.161 the section entitled "Shadowing nested dictiionaries: dict with."

Comment: Some of your other questions mention Javascript closures and lexical scoping iirc - JS has that sort of behaviour for scoped variables, as does C.  Note that the problem with invisibly overwriting variable contents with `dict with` is worse than I thought - it's not limited to variables in the local callframe but can break out with keys that look like fully qualified namespace variables.  I'd comment on Donal's answer which suggested this might be the case, but I don't have the rep to do that yet.  It's a big enough risk that I'd recommend always using `dict update` over `dict with`

Comment: I forgot to wirte that NadKarni (p. 162) recommends "adopt[ing] a convention where dictionary keys are syntactically different from variable names." I was using prefix `D_` and, unless I used `dict with` on two dictionaries each having the same key names in the same procedure, there was no concern overwriting variables; but, once learning about the amount of background work, I found  I could accomplish the same without it or, as I asked originally, structuring the dictionary such that the key name of interest doesn't hold the data but a generic name under it, unpacking far fewer keys.

Answer (score 2):

The `dict with` command does a lot of work by comparison with most Tcl commands. What it does:

1. Reads the top-level dictionary (henceforth **T** below) from the variable you give.
2. Follows the path you specify into the nested dictionary (henceforth **D** below).
3. Gets the sequence of keys in **D** and *remembers* them (internally it's a Tcl list but you never see it).
4. For each key in that sequence of keys, it copies the value associated with it out of **D** and stores it in a variable with the same name as the key. If a key is such that it cannot be used as a variable or cannot be written to, it's an error. (I don't *think* they have to be local variables.)
5. It runs your body script. The result tuple (value, result code, etc.) is remembered.
6. For each remembered key, it copies the value from the variable with that name and stores it in **D** (making a copy of the dictionary if necessary). *If the variable is deleted,* the key/value pair is removed. (**Consequence:** you can also directly update **D** within **T** in the body script to add new keys; those will be ignored/preserved by this post-body update stage. Writing a non-dictionary to that part of **T** results in an error.)
7. It stores the updated **D** back into the right place in/below **T** and **T** is written back to the variable in which it is held (i.e., write traces are fired). If the write back of **D** or **T** fails, it's an error.
8. The result tuple (from stage 5) becomes the overall result of `dict with` *unless* an error happens during stages 6 and 7; I can't remember off the top of my head how errors there are handled when there is also an error from the body.

**Special case:** If the body is the *empty string*, steps 5–8 are skipped and the result the remembering of the key sequence (step 3) is only used for step 4. (It uses a different bytecode sequence too.)

---

I **recommend** only using `dict with` inside a procedure (or lambda term, or method; anything with a Local Variable Table in the stack frame). This is also true for `dict update` though rather less pressing.

I **recommend** only using `dict with` when the dictionary being expanded follows a schema that you already know. This is not generally true for all dictionaries — supporting arbitrary keys was a foundational design decision of Tcl's dictionaries — but can certainly be true for the specific cases you'd likely use with `dict with`. Note that `dict update` does not have that restriction, as you are supplying the variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and recommendations. Step 4 is the one that I was wondering about because, if don't take care in structuring the dictionary, I could end up copying a whole lot of values that aren't needed in the body script..  Even for an empty body, if I understand correctly, step 4 will still copy all the values rather than point to them.